# Is there a specific Syntax for being able to use ROW_NUMBER() in Hibernate and Spring integrated, using native queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, native

When trying to pull up only a certain amount of results for each page, I would like to use the ROW_NUMBER() function. Based on the page the user is on, I only want to display 20, 30, or 50 results (depending on their preferences). I used the code below, and it works in MS SQL Server 2016, but when I put it into @Query, I get an error. This is the code:

```
@Query(value="
USE [BadgerNames]
GO
WITH BakedBadgers AS
(
SELECT CoreBadger_ID,CreatedDate,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BirthDate) AS RowNumber
 FROM dbo.ALL_OF_THE_BADGERS
)
SELECT CoreBadger_ID, BirthDate, RowNumber
FROM BakedBadgers
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ?#{ #pageable.offset -1}
AND ?#{#pageable.offset + #pageable.pageSize}",
nativeQuery = true)

Page<Item> findActiveItemsByLocation(Pageable pageable);
```

I get the following errors.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

---Edit---

After further investigation and help from the comments below, it looks like the issue might be intertwined with the pageable command. When I run the code on the site without the pageable, it runs correctly. The introduction of the code below seems to break it.

```
Page<Item> findActiveItemsByLocation(Pageable pageable);
```

We’re following the example here: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L539

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put a CTE into a JDBC query.  Try putting the following query into a native JDBC query:

```
SELECT CoreBadger_ID, BirthDate, RowNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT CoreBadger_ID,
           CreatedDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BirthDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM dbo.ALL_OF_THE_BADGERS
)
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;

Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT CoreBadger_ID, BirthDate, RowNumber FROM ... where RowNumber BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2");
q.setParameter(1, "50");
q.setParameter(1, "60");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It seems like the
`Page<Item> findActiveItemsByLocation(Pageable pageable);`
is what is breaking the whole process.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the page-able dynamic sorting. Does anyone know if you can use page-able dynamic sorting with Spring and Hibernate without getting the error listed in the question?

Comment: @Jolley71717 did you found any solution to this?